# JavaScript Chrome extension- Send Message after create new Tab from popup to content

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

in a popup.js of my extention, i want to create a new tab and send a message. content.js has to listen the message and answer but it doesn't work! i tried a lot of solution found in other question but without success
here my files:

```
{
  //Manifest.json
  "name": "Stampa cedolini",
  "description": "stampa automatica dei cedolini",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
      "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
   ],

  "content_scripts":  [{
     "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
     "js": [ "jquery-2.1.3.min.js" ,"content.js"]
   }],

  "browser_action": {
       "default_title": "Scegli la persona.",
       "default_icon": "icon.png",
       "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

popup.js:

```
function click(e) {
    var link1 = "http://www.example1.it";

var link2 = "http://www.example2.com";
if (e.target.id === "pippo") {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: link1 }, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            // your code ...
            chrome.tabs.executeScript({code:"console.log('"+tabs[0].id+"')"});
            //chrome.tabs.executeScript({code:"alert("+tabs[0].id+");"});
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {persona: "pippo"});
        });
    });
} else {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: link2 }); 
}
 //window.close();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
   for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
   divs[i].addEventListener('click', click);
}
});
```

and content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
     alert("from a content script:" + sender.tab.url);
     if (request.persona == "pippo") {
         sendResponse({risp: "ricevuto"});
     }
});
```

the console.log(tab.id) in tabs.create callback is printed but seems that fails the send message 
Can someone help me??
thanks

Comment: @Adam While your edit improved grammar, it introduced a few conceptual mistakes. I rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your content script it loaded, by default, at `document_idle`.

Which means that by the time you send the message, it's not there yet, and nothing listens to your message.

If you are creating a tab from code, it's best to programmatically inject your content script and not rely on the manifest injection, and use the callback to ensure it's done executing.

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: link1 }, function(tab) {
  // Why do you query, when tab is already given?
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"jquery-2.1.3.min.js"}, function() {
    // This executes only after jQuery has been injected and executed
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"jcontent.js"}, function() {
      // This executes only after your content script executes
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {persona: "pippo"});
    });
  });
});
```

That said, you may want to consider calling this code in the background script and not in the popup. As soon as popup loses focus, your popup page starts to unload and your code may not finish executing. It's better if you message the background script with a request to create the tab.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion and explanations! i'm new of chrome extensions...i will try this evening and let you know.

Comment: thanks a lot! now it works!! finaly i understood how extentensions exchange message!

Comment: save my day. I was everything right and didn't understand the timing issue..

Comment: Update for Manifest v3: chrome.tabs.executeScript has been replaced by [chrome.scripting.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) with a different method signature.  It may also required adding [host_permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/) for the target tab to the manifest.