# Chrome extension create tab and send msg to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I tried different things, but it doesn't work. 
In my popup.html i've created a button. When i click it, i wan't to create a new tab and send to it a message. Here is the code:

```
$("#openLink").click(function () {
           chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://jquery.com'}, function (tab) {
                console.log(tab.id);
                alert(tab.id);
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, 'hello');
            });

        });
```

And in the content script i try to use this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        alert('message received');
    });
```

But it doesn't alert me nothing.
Please help.

Comment: [chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging)???

Comment: Yes, sorry, but it didn't helped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Chrome extension- Send Message after create new Tab from popup to content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086759/javascript-chrome-extension-send-message-after-create-new-tab-from-popup-to-con)

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to make it work by adding a delay between the tab creation and the send message method, this is probably not the ideal solution but it should work:

```
$("#openLink").click(function () {
           chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://jquery.com'}, function (tab) {
                console.log(tab.id);
                alert(tab.id);
                setTimeout(function(){
                     chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, 'hello');
                },1000)
            });

        });
```